# Install a package on specific platforms only

Tags: vcpkg

Let's say I have the following vcpkg manifest:

```json
{
  "dependencies": [
    {
      "name": "nlohmann-json",
      "version>=": "3.11.3"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there a way to specify that I only want this dependency on Cent 7?